# how to create a simple puzzle/quizzes widget platform by using html5

Tags: html

i want to create a simple puzzle/quizzes widget platform which using HTML5 from the beginning. this widget enable low end user to create their own quizzes or puzzle or any simple games. how do i start and what i need in order to do this?